# i had newly installed the magento 2 and this problem is occuring with elasticsearch please help

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch

[image]

i had newly installed the magento 2 and this problem is occuring with elasticsearch please help

Comment: what is the host for your elasticsearch installation? also are you trying to establish the communication between Magento and ES with TLS?

Comment: my hosting provider is fastcomet.com

Comment: this is not what i am asking :) what did you enter in 'Elasticsearch Server Hostname' configuration in magento admin?

Comment: i did not enter anything right now please suggest me what to do because it is  fresh insatllation

Comment: ok, but do you have Elasticsearch installed on your server?

Comment: i had installed only magento 2.4

Comment: i added my thoughts on this in an answer to your post. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided in the comments section, it seems that you didn't install Elasticsearch prior to installing Magento.

Please follow the guidelines provided here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/elasticsearch.html

Other resources you might find useful:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html
- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/elasticsearch/configure-magento.html

Good luck!